# Solution Verification: Question about expectations of sum of dice rolls.

Tags: probability, solution-verification, expected-value

> We keep throw a green and red fair dice together, until the green die gets $1,3,5$ as a result. (the throws/dice are independent). 
> What is the expected value of the sum of green die / red die?

My Solution: 
Let $Y$ be the value of the sum of the green die, and let $X$ be the number of throws, which means $X\sim Geo(\frac{1}{2})$. 
$E(Y)=E(E(Y|X))=E[3.5(X-1)+\frac{1+3+5}{6}]$ 
Explanation: The expected value of each throw of a regular fair die is $E(Y)=\frac{1+2+3+4+5+6}{6}=3.5$, but the last throw we know that $Y$ Cannot be $2,4,6$ so I just removed them out of the sum. 
Thus $E(Y)=3.5E(X)-2=7-2=5$. 
For the red die, it's just a normal die so its equal to $E(3.5X)=7$.

Comment: Singularis: die. Pluralis: dice. Are things in accordance with that in your question? If not then please edit.

Comment: The early Green dice throws must be $2,4,6$ with an average per roll of $4$ not $3.5$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Expected Value of the sum of rolls of the green die,

$ \displaystyle \small E = \frac{1}{6} \cdot ((2 + E) + (4 + E) + (6 + E)) + \frac{1}{6} \cdot (1 + 3 + 5)$

$ \implies E = 7$

Or using your approach,

$ \displaystyle \small E(Y)=E(E(Y|X))=E \left[\frac{2+4+6}{3}(X-1)+\frac{1+3+5}{3}\right]$

$ \displaystyle \small  = 4 E(X) - 1 = 4 \cdot 2 - 1 = 7$

and it turns out to be the same as Expected Value of the sum of the red die.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution works fine, an easier way would be to recursively condition on the first green die. $\frac{1}{2}$ the time it's odd and the game stops and $\frac{1}{2}$ it's even and the game keeps going. Let $X$ denote your final score and so :

$\mathbb{E}[X] = \frac{1}{2}(3+3.5) + \frac{1}{2}(4+3.5+\mathbb{E}[X])$

Hence $\mathbb{E}[X] = 14$

Alternatively: you will have on average $4$ dice rolls, $2$ of each die, $4$ rolls have expected sum $\frac{7}{2} \cdot 4 = 14$.

More formally letting $X_i$ denote the running sum of both die, the  Markov chain $Y_i := X_i - 7i$, $Y_0 = 0$ is a martingale with a.s finite stopping, $\tau$, first visit to $\{1,3,5\}$ on green die and so $\mathbb{E}[Y_{\tau}] = 0  $. 
And so $\mathbb{E}[X_{\tau}] = \mathbb{E}[7\mathbb{\tau}] =14$ which you correctly found from $\tau$ being geometric has expectation $2$.